# Can't trigger more than 1 notification for geofences

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm making a note app that trigger notificaitions when you enter a geofence if I make more than 1 note with the same location when I enter it only on geofence triggers and only shows 1 notification.

Here is the code:
Broadcast Receiver

```
    class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       //if (intent.action == ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT) {
            val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)

            if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                val errorMessage = errorMessage(context, geofencingEvent.errorCode)
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
                return
            }

            if (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
                Log.v(TAG, "context.getString(R.string.geofence_entered)")

                val fenceId = when {
                    geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.isNotEmpty() ->
                        geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences
                    else -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "No Geofence Trigger Found! Abort mission!")
                        return
                    }
                }

                /*val foundIndex = GeofencingConstants.LANDMARK_DATA.indexOfFirst {
                    it.id == fenceId
                }*/

                // Unknown Geofences aren't helpful to us
                /*if ( -1 == foundIndex ) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unknown Geofence: Abort Mission")
                    return
                }*/

                for (geofence in fenceId){
                    sendGeofenceEnteredNotification(
                        context, geofence.requestId, intent.getStringExtra("note")!!
                    )
                }

            }
        }
   // }
}
```

-------------- Methods for adding geofencing ---------------------------

```
private fun createPendingIntent(context: Context, note: Note) : PendingIntent{
    val intent = Intent(context, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = "MainActivity.treasureHunt.action.ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT"
    intent.putExtra("note", note.note)
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, note.date.toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}


fun addGeofenceForNote(note: Note, context: Context) {
    val geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context)

    val geofence = Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId(note.id)
        .setCircularRegion(note.latitude, note.longitude, GeofencingConstants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
        .build()

    // Build the geofence request
    val geofencingRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder()
        .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        .addGeofence(geofence)
        .build()

    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, createPendingIntent(context, note))?.run {
        addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.e("Add Geofence", geofence.requestId)
        }
        addOnFailureListener {
            if ((it.message != null)) {
                Log.w("TAG", it.message!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made 3 notes with the same location and the 2nd one was the one that trigger the broadcastreceiver.

P.S. even if the geofence are in totally different locations I still can only get 1 notification. As far as I can see all pending intents and notification get different IDs.

Ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

the problem wasa the phone for some reason couldnt create all the notifications.

the code that fixed it was the `.apply{}` on the notificationManager

```
fun NotificationManager.handleNotification(context: Context, geofences: List<Geofence>){
    val list = ArrayList<Notification>()
    val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    val notificationIdBase = (Date().time / 1000L % Int.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
    apply {
        for (i in geofences.indices){
            val notificationId = notificationIdBase + i
            val notification = createGroupNotification(context, notificationId, geofences[i].requestId)
            list.add(notification)
            notify(notificationId, notification)
            set.add(notificationId)
            Log.d("TAG", notificationId.toString())
        }
        Log.d("TAG", geofences.size.toString() + " " + list.size + " " + set.size)
    }
}
```